# Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver and Appium AndroidDriver in the same code?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, appium, cucumber-java

I need to automate web calling functionality b/w android app and chrome web (local computer). Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver and Appium AndroidDriver in the same code?

Steps-

1. Open android app and initiate a call, the call should land on web browser
2. Login to web application and accept the call'

Can anyone help?

How to initialize both android driver and web driver in same java program?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of each driver.  Store them in separate variables.  Don't make things static. You can have multiple drivers going at the same time.